# Cannot be opened because its project type (.csproj) is not supported by this version of the application. VS 2008

Tags: .net, visual-studio

[image]

Here's files that are installed related to VS 2008 in Program and features In Control Panel. I am not sure whether VS has been installed Properly  ?

Also The application I am trying to open that has created in VS 2008 itself still I am getting above error.

Comment: It has not been installed properly.  The "Shell" version is not VS and cannot open C# projects, it was meant as a tool to help people to develop their own language IDE.  You can't get VS2008 for free, given its age you'll need an MSDN subscription or an auction site like Ebay.

Comment: Thanks @Hans Passant.